# Laravel Eloquent - get last insert of related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a relationship between two models: `Terminal` and `terminalRent`.

A Terminal can have many terminalRents.
I want to get the last Rent for a specific Terminal.

```
$lastRent = Terminal::with('terminalRent')->where('id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

When using `where()` it will reflect those on the `Modal` hoewever I want to get the last record for terminalRent in relation to the specific terminal. `$id` is the Id of the terminal and the tables are connected like this:

```
Terminal
----
ID


terminalRent
-----
ID
terminal_id <--- this is the foreign key for the ID of the Terminal Table
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Adrenaxus I'm using 5.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the relationship between Terminal and Terminal rent is hasMany you can do something like:

```
$lastRented = $lastRent->terminalRent->last();
```

Ensure you have the last rented via `dd($lastRented);`

Let me know how you get on

Edit: If this gives you the incorrect instance of terminalRent try first(); I can't remember how Eloquent orders eagerlaoded relationships by default.

Comment: This works like a charm: `$lastRent = Terminal::with('terminalRent')->where('id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $lastRented = $lastRent->TerminalRent->first();` I just don't know why, because I used two times first(), it's a bit confusing. Can you maybe explain it? Thanks

Comment: Ofcourse - So, we have two commonly used ways of finalising a query, get(); and first(); - Running get(); will return a collection where first returns a single object from that query, in your case the relationship TerminalRent returns a collection, by calling first(); you obtain the first instance of that object. You can prove it's a collection by visiting the Laravel docs collection methods and testing any of those on there.

Comment: In your case you can do it just like this : `$lastRent = Terminal::with('terminalRent')->where('id', $id)->get(); $lastRented = $lastRent->TerminalRent->first();` :)

Comment: @Maraboc This doesnt work `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$TerminalRent` But Terminal´Rent exists, since i was using it already, lol. Thanks anyway :) @excojish Thank you!

Comment: Try this one : `$lastRent = Terminal::with('terminalRent')->where('id', $id)->get(); $lastRented = $lastRent->TerminalRent()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();` !

Comment: @Maraboc this wont work, $lastRent will not contain the property TerminalRent because it's a collection, he will need to loop through them to access the TerminalRent property..

Answer (score 3):

Try This Code

```
$lastRent =  Terminal::with(['terminalRent' => function ($query) { 
                        $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
                }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join them and then order the results based on `terminalRent.id` and pick the first one:

```
$lastRent = Terminal::join('terminalRent', 'terminalRent.terminal_id','=','Terminal.id')->where('Terminal.id', $id)->orderBy('terminalRent.id', 'desc')->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

@Parithiban Solution is very useful but this function run one query two times

for better performance try this

```php
$lastRent =  Terminal::with(['terminalRent' => function ($query) { 
  return $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the last rent for a specific Terminal:

```
$terminal = Terminal::find($id); //the terminal for which you want to get the last rent
$lastRent = $terminal->rentals()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

Keep in mind that this is only one way to do it, there might be other options that suit your needs better.

Comment: What is `rentals()`? Should that be the TerminalRent-Model?

Comment: `rentals()` or `rents()` (I'm not sure about the spelling) would be the relation between Terminals and Rents as defined in your Terminal model: `public function rents(){return $this->hasMany('Rent');}`

Comment: Ah, okay, Thanks. Sadly this doesn't work either, since I'm getting returned rows of other terminals.

Comment: Please specify what exactly doesn't work. I tested it with my 1:n relations and it definetely _does_ work.